# How do I fix a "missing delegate marshalling data" error with DateTime.ToString() in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, datetime, .net-core, datetime-format

I wrote this program for minimal error reproduction:

```
using System;

namespace HelloDates
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            var today = DateTime.Today;
            Console.WriteLine("I know what day it is!");
            string today_fmt = today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
            Console.WriteLine($"Today is {today_fmt}.");
        }
    }
}
```

Added Microsoft.DotNet.ILCompiler, published with CoreRT, ran, and got this result:

```
Hello World!
I know what day it is!
Unhandled Exception: EETypeRva:0x00283B48: EETypeRva:0x00295C98 is missing delegate marshalling data. To enable delegate marshalling data, add a MarshalDelegate directive to the application rd.xml file. For more information, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=393965
   at HelloDates!<BaseAddress>+0x5fed
   at HelloDates!<BaseAddress>+0xfddcf
   at HelloDates!<BaseAddress>+0x1458fb
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConditionalWeakTable`2.GetValue(TKey, ConditionalWeakTable`2.CreateValueCallback) + 0x3d
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.PInvokeMarshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(Delegate) + 0x83
   at HelloDates!<BaseAddress>+0xb6c38
   at HelloDates!<BaseAddress>+0xb9ab8
   at System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.set_Calendar(Calendar) + 0x94
   at System.Globalization.CultureInfo.get_DateTimeFormat() + 0x57
   at System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetFormat(Type) + 0x88
   at System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.get_CurrentInfo() + 0x50
   at System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.GetInstance(IFormatProvider) + 0x8b
   at HelloDates!<BaseAddress>+0x9b630
   at HelloDates!<BaseAddress>+0x9b4bd
   at HelloDates.Program.Main(String[]) + 0x62
   at HelloDates!<BaseAddress>+0x155416
```

Clearly, the error comes when the program tries to format the date. But I don't know what delegate marshalling data or an EETypeRva are, I don't have an rd.xml file anywhere I can see, and I can't understand the linked document. Something about reflection?

What's especially frustrating is that in an earlier version of the program where I originally encountered the error, ToString() worked just fine, even compiling to native code, and I can't figure out what might've changed.

Comment: Depending on CoreRT today is, erm, courageous.  Very, very important to understand the significance of rd.xml btw.  But you shouldn't need it for framework types, click the [New Issue button](https://github.com/dotnet/corert/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen) to let them know.  After checking that it is not a calendar issue that is specific to your locale, test it with en-US first.  Do finish your SO profile so we can tell where you come from.